# Why is my terminal freezing up?

Tags: 10.04, command-line, freeze

Sometimes when my terminal freezes up and it will not let me type. I can not identify any causes, nor how to diagnose. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

GNOME Terminal 2.30.2 on Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: usually when the terminal freezes it is caused by another application in the background using too many resources, like the CPU or Disk I/O. If you run `top` in a terminal, you should be able to locate the problem easily.

Comment: @roland - sounds like a catch-22, but good advice since sometimes when one terminal is frozen I can open another and it will work.

Comment: I Know right? :) It is a bit of a catch-22, but it often works for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A good general way to diagnose mysterious hangs:

1. open a(nother) terminal, and use `ps axo pid,wchan:32,cmd` to find the other process id
2. note the `wchan` column, which should tell you whether it's stuck in the kernel
3. run `sudo strace -p PID` inserting the pid of that process; paste that into a bug report or question

If there's anything aside from just a dash in the wchan column, then the process is in the kernel doing something.  Some typical values:

- `futex_wait_queue_me` - waiting on a futex for another thread in the same process
- `poll_schedule_timeout` - waiting for network or interprocess communication, or just sleeping for a while
- `pipe_wait` - reading/writing a pipe

There are thousands of possibilities so I can't list them all.  See [What is the "Waiting Channel" of a process?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19442/what-is-the-waiting-channel-of-a-process) for more.

Comment: Very useful for general purpose bug tracking. Can you please update your answer with some extensive description ? What message in wchan column indicates a program that is stuck in the kernel ?

Comment: Thanks, Salih.  Maybe we should have another question about how in general to diagnose hangs?

Comment: If people are curious about any other wchan values, please add a comment.

Comment: Any `wchan` means the process is waiting in the kernel. If it stays there for a long time and for no good reason like listening for network io, then it's stuck. ;)

Comment: I have `do-epoll-wait` and `do-wait` in the `wchan` column related to `.vscode-server` which should be fine listening to `remote wsl` connection.

Answer (score 37):

Did you press Ctrl+S by any chance?  It's the terminal pause key that stops all output until you press Ctrl-Q to resume.

Comment: what could be the reason behind providing the option to pause the terminal, just curious to know.

Comment: Sometimes it's helpful, when an application is printing lots of output non-stop, and you want to make it pause so you can read it before it disappears off screen.

It's also the same control character used for [software flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control), when one device wants to tell the other device to slow down for a bit.

Comment: @learner The Control-S opton is a relict from old times up to about the 1980-ies when the computer was operated using a teletype, or teletype-like text-based video terminal. Even worse, the computer output often was concise and cryptic, so pausing was convenient to get some more time to study the messages before these would disappear past the top of the screen